# MySql performance issues in queries

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm a newbie using MySql. I'm reviewing a table that has around 200,000 
records. When I execute a simple:

```
 SELECT * FROM X WHERE Serial=123
```

it takes a long time, around 15-30 secs in return a response (with 200,000 rows) .

Before adding an index it takes around 50 seconds (with 7 million) to return a simple select where statement. 
This table increases its rows every day. Right now it has 7 million rows. I added an index in the following way:

```
 ALTER TABLE `X` ADD INDEX `index_name` (`serial`)
```

Now it takes 109 seconds to return a response.

1. Which initial approaches should I apply to this table to improve the performance?
2. Is MySql the correct tool to handle big tables that will have around 5-10 million of records? or should I move to another tool?

Comment: Do you have index on ID column?

Comment: yes,it does. There is an index for this column.

Comment: please post the result from **EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM X WHERE Id='123'**

Comment: maybe it is doing a cast. How about just id=123. `Show create table x` could clear up our assumptions

Comment: Thank you for your comments.I edited the question with more details.

Comment: It seems adding the index to that column decreases the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `serial` is some kind of numeric datatype...

You do `ADD INDEX` only *once*.  Normally, you would have foreseen the need for the index and add it very cheaply when you created the table.

Now that you have the index on `serial`, that select, with any value other than `123`, will run very fast.

If there is only one row with `serial = 123`, the indexed table will spit out the row in milliseconds whether it has 7 million rows or 7 billion.

If `serial = 123` shows up in 1% of the table, then finding all 70M rows (out of 7B) will take much longer than finding all 70K rows (out of 7M).

Indexes are your friends!

If `serial` is a `VARCHAR`, then...

Plan A:  Change `serial` to be a numeric type (if appropriate), or

Plan B:  Put quotes around `123` so that you are comparing strings to strings!